# Multinominal Regression Test

Tags: regression

If I have 3 IVs that are categorical/nominal and 1 DV that is categorical/nominal not rank or order, can I run a multinominal regression?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by a "multinominal regression"?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean multinomial logistic regression and yes, that would be the usual starting place for this situation, unless there are other aspects that you haven't mentioned.